# what are inline operators C

Tags: c, macros, operators, inline

What are inline operators in C language?

I found this concept here: "until the inline operator becomes part of standard C, macros are the only portable way of generating inline code".

[Source](https://rmbconsulting.us/publications/a-c-test-the-0x10-best-questions-for-would-be-embedded-programmers/)

Comment: Has been for 18... err 19 years. It means the *`inline` keyword*

Comment: Copypasting your exact title into a popular search engine gives: 'About 6,270,000 results'.   I'm sure a few will prove useful.

Answer (score 1):

When you mark a function as `inline`, compiler merges body of that function into `caller`, so there is no extra effort to call the function, also compiler can do more optimization in the body of the caller and function.

if you have this function:

```
inline int min(int a, int b) {
    return a <= b? a: b;
}
```

when you calll this function, compiler won't use `call`, it will merge this code into caller code

Comment: Not completely true: `inline`, but also `register` are just suggestions to the compiler. The compiler will still decide what's best. (Actually a good compiler will inline small functions even without marking them with `inline`.)

Comment: true, smart comiplers do more optimizations and decide what to optimize.